# How To Retrieve Individual Google Analytics Statistics For Website

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When registering your website with Google Analytics, is it possible to then create your own dashboard on your website and retrieve individual Google Analytics data segments instead of logging into Google and watch the statistics from there?

In short building your own dashboard, using Google Analytics data? Perhaps Google Analytics have some sort of API one can use to specify what to return to the website to display?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also checkout the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide). it makes creating dashboards simple by making the auth step simple.

Answer (score 1):

Just google for the question.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/

and probably this is the best tool you can get from anywhere to fetch all your data :

http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Comment: This looks like an awesome tool!